# Python, making multiple (dots) look cleaner

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For python in general or maybe just pandas, is there a better or cleaner way to do multiple `.`(dots)?
For example, say I have a code snippet like so:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='bar')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'value': 'foo'}, inplace=True)
```

How can I make something like this look cleaner? Like this:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='bar')
    .dropna(inplace=True)
    .drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)
    .reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    .rename(columns={'value': 'foo'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: put parentheses at the start and end of your code. besides, if you are going to be chaining your methods, then do not use `inplace=True`

Comment: @sammywemmy Thank you for that suggestion! I never realized it would be so simple.

Comment: https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what the functions return. The `df` object has those methods, but what those methods return doesn't. So there isn't a strict way to "make the dots look nicer" unless you modify Panda's code. The methods must return an object with the same methods so getting rid of the `inplace=True` argument will also fix it. Panda's returns `None` otherwise.

Essentially, the `inplace` is modifying the `df` object and doesn't return it. Without that the methods will return an object that has the same methods, so try:

```
df = (
    pd.melt(df, id_vars='bar')
      .dropna()
      .drop('variable', axis=1)
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      .rename(columns={'value': 'foo'})
)
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was wondering why it would give me an error of `NoneType` sometimes when I would try to chain them. Thank you for that!

Comment: Yes, so it looks like Pandas returns `None` if it's run in place. If you make your own objects (classes) you can do the same thing by `return self` to chain methods.

Comment: You need parentheses around the entire chain for it to work without line continuation characters